# What does :$s do?

Tags: vim, vi

Instead of typing:

```
:%s/a/b/g
```

I accidentally typed:

```
:$s/a/b/g
```

Then Vim highlights all "a".

I then tried:

```
:%s/a/
```

It also highlights all "a"s, but if I run the command again, it says "a" is not found.

So what is the proper use of `:$s`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` in this case refers to a range. The command `:$s/a/b/g` performs the replacement only on the last line of the file, however matches (`a`s) are highlighted everywhere, in both cases.

For more information, see `:h range` and `:h :s`.

Comment: The usual `%` is also a range, equivalent to `1,$`, referring to the entire file.